# Ignore "no-cache" header?

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome

I use Ubuntu, and Google Chrome mostly. How can I kill these HTTP headers, so that my browser caches this data? **I believe it is XHR.** Here are the relevant HTTP response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma:no-cache
```

I also have Firefox, is there a plugin or something I can use to not respect "no-cache" ? Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to grab an mp3 from a site that looks like it specifically doesn't want you to do so?

Comment: Why isn't manually downloading the MP3 file sufficient?

Comment: I don't have a direct link, that's why I want it to save to my disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite universal way might be to set up a local proxy (like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)), and setting it either to remove that header, or to ignore it and cache the file for you.

Comment: I have installed Squid before.. but I couldn't figure out how to use it. But if you could tell me what to put in the config file [squid.conf?] to ignore [or maybe rewrite] the no-cache header, that would be awesome!

Comment: update. 
I googled around and I found the correct command to put in /etc/squid/squid.conf:
header_access Cache-Control deny all

Answer (score 3):

As @che mentioned a local proxy like Squid do this.

Edit the config in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`.

You may work headers using `request_header_access` see http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/.

In this case `request_header_access Cache-Control deny all`.

Also have a look at the config for `refresh_pattern` at http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/.

You may find some examples at http://archive09.linux.com/feature/153221.

Then you might want something like [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) in Chrome to control proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another lighter solution might be http://www.privoxy.org/